# The front tire of my Huffy 3 speed rubs against the right fork as it spins

Tags: wheels, fork

The front tire of my Huffy 3 speed rubs against the right fork when it spins.

Comment: Usually this means either the wheel is dramatically out of true, the tire is not evenly mounted on the wheel or the wheel in not seated properly in the fork's dropouts. Did you recently have a flat or do something else that required removing the wheel from the fork?

Comment: Did it happen all of a sudden, or gradually over time?  Did you remove the front wheel and it was bad straight after?    OR have you had a prang, or a bad landing or any other sort of heavy impact?

Comment: If it rubs continuously, most likely the wheel is simply not installed properly on the fork.  Loosen the axle bolts, make sure the axle's all the way into the slots, then tighten again.  If rubs intermittently (only for part of each full turn of the wheel) then the wheel is "sprung" and needs to be "trued".

Answer (score 4):

Hmmm. Thats a bad thing. You want to fix that.

- Most likely the front axle isn't centered in the fork when tightened down.  I'm guessing you have axle nuts and not a quick connect skewer?  You want to loosen both nuts, hold the tire centered underneath the headset (where you can easily see that the gap between the tire and the front fork is the same on both sides.)  Then carefully tighten the two nuts holding the axle to the fork (I think you need a 15mm box / open wrench for this.)
- Its possible the rim is out of true so when the axle / hub is mounted straight the rim is off to one side or the other.  Generally you see this when there are loose or broken spokes.  Tool to fix this is a simple spoke wrench and a whole lot of patience.
- It's possible you have loose or missing wheel bearings at the hub.  When you spin the wheel is everything buttery smooth? Is there any noticable slop between the axle shaft and the hub? If so, that will have to be fixed (need more tools here, including a very thin hub wrench, grease, cleaner, possibly new bearings, etc...)